# display image from bean with property "length" of the video

Tags: html, css, jsf

I need to display an image of a video object with the video length on the bottom right side of the image.

I tried this:

```html
<h:graphicImage url="#{video.picUrl}" height="30" width="30">
    <h:outputText value="#{video.Length}" />
</h:graphicImage>
```

But the length text is shown outside the image. How can I get it on the bottom right inside the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pure HTML/CSS issue. You first need to figure how the generated HTML/CSS should look like to achieve your functional requirement. For example, the following HTML

```html
<span class="imageWithText">
    <img src="some-video.png" width="30" height="30" />
    <span class="text">123</span>
</span>
```

with the following CSS

```css
.imageWithText {
    position: relative;
}
.imageWithText .text {
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 3px;
    right: 3px; 
    background-color: white;
    font-size: .5em;
}
```

should work out for you.

You see, the `.text` is absolutely positioned relative to the `.imageWithText`, with `bottom` and `right` on `3px` so that it sticks nicely to the bottom right.

Now, to generate the same HTML with JSF, the code should look like

```html
<h:panelGroup styleClass="imageWithText">
    <h:graphicImage value="#{video.picUrl}" height="30" width="30" />
    <h:outputText styleClass="text" value="#{video.length}" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

The same CSS is reuseable.